# Adding Configuration to Application Insights

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

So I recently installed Application Insights to my project through Visual Studio and it says that it is 100% configured, but there is no added code in my Startup.cs. Do I need to add anything to get it fully functional or is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to add application insights to an ASP.NET Core site.

In the `Program.cs` file:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseApplicationInsights() // Here
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Or in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration); // here
    var builder = services.AddMvc();
}
```

You need to add the instrumentation key in the `appsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "4bbb7b98-78f8-49c3-8ede-da3215b75f43"
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! It seems like it added the line you mentioned in the Program.cs file.

Comment: At least the new templates in VS 2017 add it in Program.cs.